# Get the index from sorted DataView

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, dataview

I have a sorted data view. But when I call with the index of rows, it is like not sorted. This is my code:

```
DataTable dt = inputDataTable.Clone();
for (int i = 0; i < inputDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Columns[i].DataType = Type.GetType("System.Double");
}

foreach (DataRow dr in inputDataTable.Rows)
{
    dt.ImportRow(dr);
}
dt.AcceptChanges();

DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[1].ColumnName + " ASC";
```

when I call it:

```
dv.Table.Rows[2].ItemArray[2]
```

I still get the old value (which is not sorted by column number 1). I want to get the new sorted value. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
DataView dv = inputDataTable.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[2].ColumnName + " ASC";
DataTable dT = dv.ToTable();
```

That code will be make a sorted dataview.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
dv = dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[1].ColumnName + " ASC";
```

Comment: it is not work. It get me error. `Can't implicitly convert 'string' to 'System.Data.DataView'"`